# nodemon is showing me this error how to solve it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemon

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

added this in my package.json and then run the commond **`npm run server`** it started the `nodemon server.js` but on restarting it is showing me this error

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes... 
(node:17784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: wmic process where (ParentProcessId=24008) get ProcessId 2> nul
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at kill (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:337:26)
    at Function.run.kill (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:425:7)
    at Bus.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:495:7)
    at Bus.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at restartBus (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\watch.js:228:7)
    at FSWatcher.filterAndRestart (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\watch.js:212:16)
    at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at FSWatcher.emitWithAll (C:\Users\shreya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\index.js:540:8)
(node:17784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

**here is my server.js code**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details about your code? from the error it seems like there is something with the server code. However, Can you try executing it without nodemon?

Comment: it is running without nodemon ... I run node server.js and it is running

Comment: also when i installed nodemon globally, it stop working in all other projects also , in which it was working before......it is giving same error in all my projects now

Comment: If that's the case can you give me the details about the NodeJs version and nodemon versions?

Comment: This might be related to node version update for NodeJs. You can try installing nodemon for your project using npm install nodemon --save.
and once that's done try executing the project again.

Comment: PS F:\MERN\My> node -v
v14.16.0
PS F:\MERN\My> nodemon -v
2.0.9,          and also i tried this npm install nodemon --save its not working

Comment: hey !! its working now i installed prevous version of nodemon i.e v2.0.7 gloabaly and now the error is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Try updating nodemon

```
npm i nodemon --global
```